# MATLAB reading a variable in workspace

Tags: arrays, matlab, variables, cell

In my workspace I have a variable named `result` which stores `<100x1 cell>`

In each one, so for example `result{1,1}` has the sample of data:

```
0.000   0.0080
0.020   0.0082
0.024   0.0048
0.031   0.0061
0.056   0.0100
```

What I want to be able to do is read into my variable `result` and then read all of the subsections such as `result{1,1}` and `result{23,1}` for example. I then want to be able to manipulate this data and eventually create a plot.

It would be important to be able to make a matrix (or something) for example of `result{1,1}` and then to manipulate column 1 and then plot column 1 against column 2. Is there something possible to enable me to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions :)

Comment: "_be able to make a matrix (or something) for example of result{1,1}_": but `result{1,1}` _is_ a matrix, isn't it? Just assign it to a variable: `M = result{1,1}` and manipulate it. Or directly extract columns, for example `result{1,1}(:,1)`

Comment: Excellent thanks, this is becoming daily haha. Appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is not really clear. Do you want to perform something like this?

```
for ii=1:size(result,1)
    M = result{ii,1};
    M1 = M(:,1);
    M2 = M(:,2);
    plot(M1,M2,'o');hold on
end
```

Or as suggested by @Luis Mendo you can access each column directly:

```
for ii=1:size(result,1)
    M1 = result{ii,1}(:,1);
    M2 = result{ii,1}(:,2);
    plot(M1,M2,'o');hold on
end
```

if you want to access specific cells not all of them also you can do:

```
for ii=[1,23,44,50,98]
    M1 = result{ii,1}(:,1);
    M2 = result{ii,1}(:,2);
    plot(M1,M2,'o');hold on
end
```

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I needed. Sorry that you didn't think the question was very clear